# pushMatrix, popMatrix, translate, and rotate in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

In the processing js programming language, there are some functions like `pushMatrix()`, `popMatrix()`, `translate()`, and `rotate()`. Is there any way to recreate these functions in pygame? I am making a dodger game and I thought it would be nice if the squares you were supposed to avoid were turning.

I have pygame version 1.9.6, windows 10.
Here is my python version and conda version when using the following commands:

```
(venv) C:\Users\Joshua\OneDrive\VscodePrograms\MyPythonFolder\Dodger>python --version
Python 3.7.6

(venv) C:\Users\Joshua\OneDrive\VscodePrograms\MyPythonFolder\Dodger>conda --version
conda 4.8.2

(venv) C:\Users\Joshua\OneDrive\VscodePrograms\MyPythonFolder\Dodger>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news) does not provide matrix operations. Pygame has the [pygame.math](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html) model, which provides basic vector arithmetic, but it has not concept of global matrices which are automatically applied to the coordinates (vertices) of objects.
The matrix operations in [Processing](https://processing.org/) are closely related to the [OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/index_gl.php) immediate mode ([Legacy OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL)) matrix operations.